# How to do retrain a linear regression model with a new subset using tensorflow or keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have 100 Gb of data and divided it into small subsets. I want to train the model in an incremental way using a new subset until all the algorithm is trained on all the subsets. How I can achieve this TensorFlow or sklearn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `scikit-learn` models do support incremental learning through the `partial_fit` method. A popular choice is the Stochastic Gradient Descent, which minimizes a loss function looking at one data sample at a time. Here is an example, assuming you have two chunks of data that you can load successively to memory, `(X1, y1), (X2, y2)`.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
sgd = SGDRegressor(random_state=42)

X1_scaled = scaler.partial_fit(X1).transform(X1)
sgd.partial_fit(X1_scaled, y1)

X2_scaled = scaler.partial_fit(X2).transform(X2)
sgd.partial_fit(X2_scaled, y2)
```